# MVC - Can I do ifs in views

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm pretty new to programming and I have a simple question about the MVC pattern. I started learning Laravel, which has views, controllers and models.

My question is: Can I have `if`s like this one in my views?

`<option value="dayofweek" {{Input::get('group') == 'dayofweek' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Day Of week </option>`

I have several `<option>`s in my `<select>` and it looks kind of ugly, especially when I add additional statement to the condition `Input::has('group') && ...`.

Should I build the select with its options in my controller since I have the same data there and perform all checks and then just let the view render selected and non-selected options?

PS: I know I can, but **should** I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do `if` statements in your view. It would be madness not to, since that would mean your views would be entirely static, which is pretty impractical.

***However***, it's probably a bad idea to have these statements depend on something like `Input`. Your views should be more *decoupled* than that. Imagine that you're going to use a particular view in several different scenarios; in other words, many different controllers may want to render the same view. There is no guarantee that an `Input` was used in every one of those scenarios, or what that input was called specifically. The *controller* should handle the direct input, the view should receive a variable like `$currentGroup` which the controller sets. You want to put some insulation between input and output, and not tie them together so immediately to increase re-usability and flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below,

```
<select>
        @foreach ($dropItems as $item)
            {{-- */ 
                $selected = '';
                if ( Input::has('group') && Input::get('group') == $item) {
                    $selected = 'selected';
                }
             /* --}}
             <option value="dayofweek" {{ $selected }}>Day Of week </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

OR you can use

```
{!! Form::select('day_drop_down', $daysArray , ( Input::has('group') &&  Input::get('group') == '')?Input::get('group'):0, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'productTemplate']) !!}
```

Comment: Probably I should have mentioned Laravel and should have asked my question without specifying language/framework. I don't ask how I can do it. What I'm asking is should I do that in the controller or in the view? :) I have seen both stuff to be done in some tutorials. I want to know what are the best practices. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, where does your controller reside? Are you doing server side programming? Then the controller and the model reside on the server.

If you are doing client side programming then all three layers live in the browser HTML/CSS (the view), Javascript (Controller and Model).

If the later then you should have your HTML clean :

```
<option value="dayofweek">Day Of week </option>
```

And only your Javascript (in the controller) does the manipulation :

```
 val = get('group') == 'dayofweek' ? 'selected' : ''}}
$('dayofweek').val = val;
```

(sorry the javascript is probably wrong... but you get the idea.)